# Why doesn't piping work inside a callback

Tags: node.js, stream

I have the following server:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  fs.mkdir(__dirname + '/output', function (err) {

    req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/output/file.txt'));
    res.end();

  });

}).listen(3000);
```

I am then using [request](http://github.com/mikeal/request) to pipe a stream to the server.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');

var crs = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/file.txt');
var r = request.post('http://0.0.0.0:3000');

crs.pipe(r);
```

Sometimes it works but most of the time /output/file.txt is empty. When I move the req.pipe(...) outside of the mkdir callback it works every time. Could anybody explain why it is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `mkdir` is asynchronous, the data in the request is emitted while the directory is being created. You need to instruct the stream to not emit the data until later by using `pause` and `resume`.

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  req.pause();
  fs.mkdir(__dirname + '/output', function (err) {
    req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/output/file.txt'));

    req.resume();
    res.end();
  });
}).listen(3000);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my experience is that by the time you're in the callback it is too late to `pause()` the stream. I've ended up adding an explicit buffer in front of the request stream to mitigate the issue. See https://github.com/Obvious/pipette#valve for a sketch.